# Background-clip: text; isnt working at all in css

Tags: css, background-clip

```css
.test{
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-clip: text;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue);
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello</p>
```

also when I type `background-clip:` and the autocomplete options come up for example: `border-box`, 'text' doesn't come up there at all and I've tried it on Microsoft Edge and Chrome and it still doesn't do anything at all is there any way to fix this?

I tried rearranging the properties in the CSS file and I used a new browser but that still did nothing at all

Comment: background-clip **after** background not before it

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is browser support. After a quick Google search, I found:

> The “background-clip: text” is supported in all main browsers with the Webkit prefix, it allows a background image to be clipped by a text element.

So to fix your problem simply add:

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

```css
.test {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 150px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Hello</p>
```

Comment: thats worked now thanks but do you know why it didnt just work without that? like why cant it just work without it?

Comment: ```background-clip``` on its own does work in other browsers that aren't based on WebKit (ie: Firefox). However,  ```background-clip``` doesn't work on WebKit-based browsers (ie: Chrome and Safari). Instead, you need to use the ```webkit``` preface. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip for more information about ```background-clip``` browser support.

Comment: @temaniafif posted the actual answer in the comment section of the Q

Comment: @oldboy If so than while it only not work on non Chromium browser?

Comment: works fine in chromium browsers. actually, i believe you no longer have to even use `-webkit-` in the most recent version(s) of chrome

Comment: in the demo that you created, it only appeared as if it was not working because the `p` element assumes a width of `100%`, yet the text's width was much less than this. so, what i did was change the width of `p` to match the content, which is the width of the text itself. now you can see the effect

Comment: @oldboy How long has this been the case for. This answer was written almost a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is addressing the `name` class, but your `p` element has the `test` class. Change one so that they match.

Additionally, you may need to add the `-webkit-background-clip` CSS property for this code to work on Chrome. An example of the code functioning is shown below.

```css
.name {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green, blue);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;

  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<p class="name">Hello</p>
```

Comment: i just did that and still it didnt work

Comment: @Randomguy660 Can you explain what didn't work? I've attached a code snippet for reference. This code functions for me on Firefox Developer Edition version 111.

Comment: its fine now i just needed to add -webkit to the background clip

Comment: @Brooke Try it on chrome it won't work without the ```-webkit``` preface.